# Flutter: "No permissions found in manifest for: []9" using permission_handler

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I'm developing a Flutter application where I need access to the user's gallery (photos). I'm using the permission_handler package to request permissions. I've updated my AndroidManifest.xml to include the necessary permissions:

xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

However, when I try to request gallery permissions in Flutter using:

Permission.photos.request();
I encounter this error in my logs:

```
No permissions found in manifest for: []9
I/flutter (30483): permission result: PermissionStatus.denied
```

Has anyone come across this issue when trying to access the gallery on Android 13+ using Flutter? How can I ensure permissions are correctly requested and granted for gallery images across different Android versions?

Given that READ_MEDIA_IMAGES should be the right permission for accessing photos on newer Android versions, I'm puzzled as to why I'm facing this denial.

Answer (score 0):

You need add these permission for android 13 in the android manifest file

```
<!-- Permissions options for the `storage` group -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- Read storage permission for Android 12 and lower -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!--
      Granular media permissions for Android 13 and newer.
      See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions
      for more information.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

For more info and documentation
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Answer (score 0):

Manifest file source code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

Dart file source code:

```
  Future<bool> permissionPhotoOrStorage() async {
    bool perm = false;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      perm = await permissionPhotos();
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final AndroidDeviceInfo android = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;
      final int sdkInt = android.version.sdkInt ?? 0;
      perm = sdkInt > 32 ? await permissionPhotos() : await permissionStorage();
    } else {}
    return Future<bool>.value(perm);
  }

  Future<bool> permissionPhotos() async {
    bool hasPhotosPermission = false;
    final PermissionStatus try0 = await Permission.photos.status;
    if (try0 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      hasPhotosPermission = true;
    } else {
      final PermissionStatus try1 = await Permission.photos.request();
      if (try1 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        hasPhotosPermission = true;
      } else {}
    }
    return Future<bool>.value(hasPhotosPermission);
  }

  Future<bool> permissionStorage() async {
    bool hasStoragePermission = false;
    final PermissionStatus try0 = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (try0 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      hasStoragePermission = true;
    } else {
      final PermissionStatus try1 = await Permission.storage.request();
      if (try1 == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        hasStoragePermission = true;
      } else {}
    }
    return Future<bool>.value(hasStoragePermission);
  }
```

Dependent package: [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)

I also want to pick the document in one project. So, I wrote this code. I tested code from SDK 29 to SDK 34 & it is working incredibly. Give it a try. All you need to call is the `permissionPhotoOrStorage()` function.